# ruby check if current date is within date records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a model called Absence that looks something like this

```
         :id => :integer,
:employee_id => :integer,
 :start_date => :date,
   :end_date => :date
```

I need to check if an Employee is away today, and return true if they are. Someone is away if they have an absence record that

1. Has a start date is today or before today,
2. Has an end date that is either null, or today or ahead of today.

so I need a method on the Employee that is something like

```
def is_away
  ?????
end
```

please help!

Comment: Did you try using `Time.now` for the current date and compare with your `start_date` and `end_date` attributes?

Comment: Gararth, if you found at least one of the answers helpful, please consider selecting the one you liked best.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
# add this to absence.rb
def covers_today?
  (start_date..end_date).cover?(Date.today)
end

# add this to employee.rb
def away?
  absences.any?(&:covers_today?)
end
```

After doing this just call `away?` on an `employee`:

```
@employee.away? 
# => true, if employee has an absense that covers the current date
```

Comment: Won't this iterate over all absences and check each `start_date` and `end_date` one-by-one? Wouldn't it be better to do the querying in SQL, like in Stefan's solution?

Comment: @Micha, you are right. This loads all absences and runs the check against them. This is slower than just checking for existence like Stefan does. But I am pretty sure you want to show more details about his absense (data range for example), if you found out that he is away. Or you want to show when he was gone the last time. Or how many leave days he alreday took this year. With my answer there is no need for a second database call, but Stefans solution needs a second query. And database queries usually much slower than iteration over a small array in memory. So I think it depends...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Employee has_many :absences`, this should work:

```
def away?(date = Date.today)
  absences.where('start_date <= :date AND (end_date >= :date OR end_date IS NULL)', date: date).exists?
end
```

Comment: I think this is much better than the answers so far, because it'll just do one query to find out if the user is away. Whereas in other answers you iterate over every absence and check whether the user was away in code. This should be done in the database with a simple query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too.

```
def is_away?
  (start_date <= Date.today) and (end_date.nil? or end_date <= Date.today) ? true : false
end
```

Comment: The ternary operator is useless here as you already return either `true` or `false` from your first condition, but otherwise, your solution is fine.

Comment: It should be `end_date >= Date.today`.